# Authorize attribute on a controller inside an area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Area with a few controllers inside it, decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute. I also have a few controllers outside the area. To default to the controller inside the area, I have updated my routes, to look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "e_Forms.Controllers" }
).DataTokens.Add("area","RefundRequest");
```

Now, the redirection works, when i try to access with `http://localhost:58000/`.

But, the problem here is, the authorize attribute does not redirect to the login page. The redirection happens only when I try to access using `http://localhost:58000/RefundRequest/Request`. Also, the breakpoints are not hit in the controller(but are hit inside the view) when I try to access using the former.

Please suggest what is happening here, and a workaround to this.

**EDIT 1:**

When I changed my route definition to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area="RefundRequest", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "e_Forms.Areas.RefundRequest.Controllers" }
).DataTokens.Add("area","RefundRequest");
```

the authorize attribute works fine. but then it does not allow me access to the Home controller outside of areas which is not marked with `[Authorize]`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a base controller and put the authorize attribute above class definition.

Comment: @SubashKharel I tried doing that, it didn't work.

Comment: Try mapping default route to the controller method not the Home Controller. I'm sure it works.